# Using javaScript to create table and add style to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

Could anyone tell me why the below code does not work to add a border to the table that I am creating.
Thanks

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Exam5 review</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.center
            {
                border: 1px;
                background-color: green;
                width: 500px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-left:auto; 
                margin-right:auto;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function parse()
        {
            document.open();
            document.write('<table class="center">');
            document.write('<tr><th>Course</th><th>Enrollment</th></tr>');
            document.write("</table>");
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="parse();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**1). Explanation.** It doesn't work because `document.write` (to be exact [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open)) completely overwrites the whole document structure when you insert the table. So your styles are wiped out. So don't use `document.write` ever at all. There are just a very few situations when you want to use it, and this one is not one of them.

Here is what [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open) says on `document.open`:

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.

**2). Correct approach.** If you want to insert some chunk of HTML use super cool and underestimated [**`insertAdjacentHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) method:

```
function parse() {
    var table = 
        '<table class="center">' +
            '<tr>' + 
                '<th>Course</th><th>Enrollment</th>' +
            '</tr>' + 
        '</table>';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', table);
}

parse();
```

**3). Border style.** Once the table in rendered you will find out that it's not enough to write `border: 1px;` to set a table border. You are missing color and border style definitions. It should be:

```css
border: 1px #AAA solid;
```

Documentation on [border property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8h7tw244/

Answer (score 0):

Per MDN, document.open will clear a document before opening it for writing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open

You could try something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerHTML += "<table></table>"
```

Replace the Tables with whatever you needed. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You Body tag should be before the head tag.
Write the table through javascript in a container.

```
<html>  
<body>
<head>
<title>Exam5 review</title> 
<style>
.center{
border: 1px solid red;
background-color: green;
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="container">
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function parse()
{
var cont= document.getElementById("container");
cont.innerHTML = '<table class= "center" > <tr><th>Course</th><th>Enrollment</th></tr></table>';
}parse();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function parse()
        {
            var html = '<table class="center"><tr><th>Cource</th><th>Enrollment</th></tr></table>';
            appendHtml(document.body, html); // "body" has two more children - h1 and span.

        }

        function appendHtml(el, str) {
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = str;
          while (div.children.length > 0) {
            el.appendChild(div.children[0]);
          }
        }


        </script>

</head>
<body onload="parse();">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you should avoid using `document.open`. Better use this js snippet:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<table class= "center" ><tr><th>Course</th><th>Enrollment</th></tr></table>';
```

---

In your document it should look like:
([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5ra8nuq/) for demo)

```html
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Exam5 review</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.center
            {
                border: 1px;
                background-color: green;
                width: 500px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-left:auto; 
                margin-right:auto;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.innerHTML += '<table class= "center" ><tr><th>Course</th><th>Enrollment</th></tr></table>';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```